# Googlemap shows grey box on all browsers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a simple test site to show google map [here](http://www.4phuong.vn/test.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry"></script>
<script src="js/GoogleMap/GoogleMap_thread_view.js"></script>
<link href="js/GoogleMap/GoogleMap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#googlemap").GoogleMap({addr: "105K Ho Thi Ky Phuong 1 Quan 10 Ho Chi Minh", lat: 43.37049234, lng: 30.3480382});
    /*var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemap'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });*/
});</script>
</head>
<body style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">
    <div id="googlemap" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px; ">abc</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The page just shows grey div without map.
I searched around on this site but nothing works (resize window event, overflow: visible, width: 100% ... etc ...)

The thing is when I uncomment the Google's sample code, it works. So there must be something wrong with my script, file GoogleMap_thread_view.js

```
(function ($) {
var map, place, myMarker;
$.widget('4phuong.GoogleMap', {
    options: {
        addr: 'unknown',
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
        zoom: 2
    },

    _create: function () {
        var $widget = this;
        $widget.element.children().hide();
        $widget._$container = $('<div class="googlemap-container"><div class="map-canvas"></div></div>');
        $widget.element.append($widget._$container);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng($widget.options.lat, $widget.options.lng),
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
            },
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('map-canvas')[0], mapOptions);

        myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: $widget.options.addr,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng($widget.options.lat, $widget.options.lng)
        });
    },

    destroy: function () {
        this._$container.remove();
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
        this.element.show();
    },

    control: function () {
        return this._$control;
    }
});
}(jQuery));
```

Could someone please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: What is `js/GoogleMap/GoogleMap_thread_view.js` and `js/GoogleMap/GoogleMap.css`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: you're referring to `document.getElementsByClassName('map-canvas')` for your map, but you're only creating that element dynamically earlier in the JS with `$widget._$container = $('<div class="googlemap-container"><div class="map-canvas"></div></div>');`  - does the `getElementsByClassName` actually return you the map div?

Comment: Hi @duncan. Yes, it does. Because I put the script in document.ready of jQuery. I can see the browser show grey box. When I use developer tool to view the DOM, I also see the elements of Googmap is generated.

Comment: There is a syntax error in the posted code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate where is the error? You can visit the sample link I posted to double check.

Comment: There is an extra `});` just before the `</script>`.  It is there on your link as well.

Comment: It's for the $(document).ready(function () {

Answer (score 1):

I know the reason. It's because I didn't give value to the field "zoom" when creating map. It should look like below

```
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng($widget.options.lat, $widget.options.lng),
            zoom: $widget.options.zoom,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
            },
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false
        };
```

It's really stupid as Google should make default value for it.

Comment: Yes, it's weird implementation of Google in my point of view. It took me many days investigating :-)

Comment: Very true.. when i compared the commented code in the html and that of the GoogleMap_thread_view.js, the only option missing was zoom, generally speaking, if zoom was not specified, the plugin should take some default value, but that's not happening