# HTML5 geolocation tracking does not return correct coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I have a small javascript as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var myLat = 0, myLng = 0;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        myLat = position.coords.latitude;
        myLng = position.coords.longitude;}
    );
}
alert(myLat +';'+myLng);
});
</script>
```

I tested and allowed the location tracking on IE11, Opera 29. I enabled debug in developer mode and found that IE11 and Opera 29 act differently.

- IE11: it runs alert first then goes to getCurrentPosition
- Opera 29: runs alert but does not go to getCurrentPosition

Could someone explain?

Comment: You should execute the 'alert' inside your callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/480qLqr9/6/

```
var myLat = 0, myLng = 0;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
  myLat = position.coords.latitude;
  myLng = position.coords.longitude;
  getPos(myLat,myLng);
},
function (error) { 
  if (error.code == error.PERMISSION_DENIED)
      console.log("Blocked");
});
}

function getPos(lat,lng){
console.log(lat,lng)
//your logic here

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I want.

Comment: BTW, could you please help me look at the issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284159/

Comment: @YukiSakura:- If this answer helped you then do accept it as an answer as that would help others facing the same issue in future.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your alert code in the callback of the `getCurrentPosition` call:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        myLat = position.coords.latitude;
        myLng = position.coords.longitude;
        alert(myLat +';'+myLng);
    });
}
```

As otherwise you are alerting before the values have been set.

Comment: Also add the error callback, this can handle exceptions like if the user blocks the feature

Comment: Thanks @Ian Devlin. Do you know how to record the correct values from callback function and use it outside? Or is it impossible?

Comment: You can call a function from the callback with the lat and lng value as parameters